# How to fix warning format JSON deprecation in cucumber 4.1.0 gem?

Tags: json, ruby, cucumber, reporting

I've recently updated to the latest Ruby cucumber gem and now getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: --format=json is deprecated and will be removed after version 5.0.0.
Please use --format=message and stand-alone json-formatter.
json-formatter homepage: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-formatter#cucumber-json-formatter.
```

I'm using json output later for my reporting. In my `cucumber.yml` I have the following default profile:

```
default:
  -r features
  --expand -f pretty --color
  -f json -o reports/cucumber.json
```

According to the reference https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-formatter#cucumber-json-formatter they say to use something like

```
cucumber --format protobuf:cucumber-messages.bin
cat cucumber-messages.bin | cucumber-json-formatter > cucumber-results.json
```

and

```
Trying it out
../fake-cucumber/javascript/bin/fake-cucumber \
--results=random \
../gherkin/testdata/good/*.feature \ | 
go/dist/json-formatter-darwin-amd64
```

But it's not really clear how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to change your cucumber profile to produce protobuf output instead of json, and then add a step to post-process the file into the json you want?

I'd assumed that the 'Trying it out' above was your output from *actually* trying it out, rather than just a straight cut and paste from the formatter's Github page...